# subclass PFObject and override init

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, initialization, pfobject

I wanted to create custom PFObject class, but it gives me a very confusing error  "Property self.photo not initialized at super.init call"

here is code of my custom class :

```
import Foundation
import Parse

class Wish: PFObject, PFSubclassing {
var id: String?
var name: String?
var descriptionWish: String?
var photo: UIImage
var photoThumbnail: UIImage
var amount: Double?
var amountDonated: Int?

static func parseClassName() -> String {
    return "Wish"
}

override init() {
    super.init()

}



convenience init(id: String?, name: String?, descriptionWish: String?, photo: UIImage, photoThumbnail: UIImage, amount: Double?, amountDonated: Int?) {
    self.init()
    self.id = id
    self.name = name
    self.descriptionWish = descriptionWish
    self.photo = photo
    self.photoThumbnail = photoThumbnail
    self.amount = amount
    self.amountDonated  = amountDonated

}
}
```

Any ideas how to make a custom initializer for this class ? 
I want to call my wish class like this:

```
Wish(id: "123", name: "xxx", descriptionWish: "Lorem ipsum", photo: photoImage, photoThumbnail: photoImageThumbnail, amount: 22.20, amountDonated: 10)
```

and cast PFObject like this

```
let wish = myPfObject as Wish
```

Any help is appreciated!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try updating your subclass to the following. Notice the `NSManaged` keywords for the Parse properties you've added to your `Wish` subclass and the removal of `super.init()`

You will probably also want to look into replacing the `UIImage` properties with the Parse-provided `PFFile` properties. You can easily store and load images using `PFImageView` included in the `ParseUI` framework.

```
import Foundation
import Parse

class Wish: PFObject, PFSubclassing {

    // MARK: - Parse Core Wish Properties

    @NSManaged var id: String?
    @NSManaged var name: String?
    @NSManaged var descriptionWish: String?
    @NSManaged var photo: UIImage
    @NSManaged var photoThumbnail: UIImage
    @NSManaged var amount: Double?
    @NSManaged var amountDonated: Int?

    // MARK: - Lifecycle

    override class func initialize() {
        struct Static {
            static var onceToken : dispatch_once_t = 0;
        }
        dispatch_once(&Static.onceToken) {
            self.registerSubclass()
        }
    }

    static func parseClassName() -> String {
        return "Wish"
    }    

    convenience init(id: String?, name: String?, descriptionWish: String?, photo: UIImage, photoThumbnail: UIImage, amount: Double?, amountDonated: Int?) {
        self.init()
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.descriptionWish = descriptionWish
        self.photo = photo
        self.photoThumbnail = photoThumbnail
        self.amount = amount
        self.amountDonated  = amountDonated
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, great answer!